# Remove Bearer Token from Email Verification

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am new to Laravel and I have implemented Email Verification but it needs a bearer token to verify the User which is not useful . How can I remove the need of bearer token from that route.
Here are the two routesm:

```
Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'sendVerificationEmail'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may customize the password reset link URL using the `createUrlUsing` method provided by the `ResetPassword` notification class. This method accepts a closure that receives the user instance that is receiving the notification as well as the password reset link token. Typically, you should call this method from your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` service provider's boot method:
You can read [here in documentation more](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#reset-link-customization)